# Print contents of log file to console output using PSEXEC

Tags: python, jenkins, psexec

*I am trying to solve an issue with Jenkins showing the status of a python script. My current path to a solution is writing the results of stdout to a text file in the script and then reading that text file as a build step (windows batch command) in Jenkins after the script is done executing. This file lives on a remote server and I am using PSEXEC to execute the script and attempt to read the log file. Below is the command I am sending*

```
psexec64 /ACCEPTEULA \\remote.ip cmd /c "type C:\file_path\git_log.txt"
```

**The log file gets all the output from stdout which is:**
​
Git repository exists

Current branch set to X

Checking out requested branch: X

The Repository data has NOT been modified

Beginning Git Pull from the repository: Flatscreen

5 seconds remaining.

4 seconds remaining.

3 seconds remaining.

2 seconds remaining.

1 second remaining.

Git Pull Complete! Begining RoboCopy

Initial Copy Completed! Beginning next RoboCopy in 5 seconds

5 seconds remaining.

4 seconds remaining.

3 seconds remaining.

2 seconds remaining.

1 second remaining.

Robocopy Completed! Your source directories are now updated with the latest code from Bitbucket

**The console output only shows the first two lines:**

Git repository exists

Current branch set to X

Checking out reconnecting to remote.ip...

Starting PSEXESVC service on the remote.ip...

Connecting with PsExec service on remote.ip...

Starting cmd on remote.ip...

cmd exited on remote.ip with error code 0.

*The job successfully reads the first two lines of the log file then loses connection. Any suggestions on how to ensure the job stays connected?*